# Yii2 Converting model objects to array with ArrayHelper::toArray()

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I am working in YII2 Framework on the following query

```
SELECT T.id, T.name, T.status, IFNULL(T.image,'no-image.png') as DP
FROM TABLE_NAME T;
```

here is my code

```
$modelTeam = Teams::find()
    ->select(
        ['T.id', 'T.name', 'T.status', 'IFNULL(T.image,"no-image.png") as DP']
    )
    ->from('{{%teams}} T')
    ->all();
```

---

**Edit:**

The result set does not include `DP` column at all why is that so, and how can I do that.

---

**Edit 2:**

While telling that the results do not include the `DP` column I missed a piece of important information that I was using the `ArrayHelper::toArray()` to convert the model object to an array and then iterate over it

```
$results=ArrayHelper::toArray($modelTeam);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem is not where I was thinking it is, the query is alright, I used `ArrayHelper::toArray($modelTeam)` method to convert the model object to an array to further iterate over the array and display all the records, and that is where the problem lies.

I needed to use the second parameter `$properties` for the `ArrayHelper::toArray()`. The second argument converts properties mapping per class, as it has problems displaying the custom declared `public` properties of a model and the `DP` is declared `public` inside the `Teams` model as it is an alias in the `ActiveRecrod` query.

```
$modelTeam = Teams::find()->
    select(['TM.id', 'TM.name', 'TM.status'])
    ->addSelect([new \yii\db\Expression('IFNULL(TM.image,\'no-image.png\') AS DP')])
    ->from('{{%teams}} TM')->all();

$results = ArrayHelper::toArray($modelTeam, [
    'common\models\Teams' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        'status',
        'DP',
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$modelTeam = Teams::find()
    ->select(['T.id', 'T.name', 'T.status'])
    ->addSelect([new Expression('IFNULL(T.image,"no-image.png") as DP')])
    ->from('{{%teams}} T')
    ->all();
$arrTeam = $modelTeam->asArray()->all();
```

Comment: pls, add explaianation of what u did

Comment: the highlight is that we can add ->asArray()->all() after model object.
then we can use the result $arrTeam as a general array like $arrTeam[0]['name'].
not sure for the alias 'DP' but hope it works.

Comment: Please add the explanation in the question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

To use IFNULL in a select with Yii2 you must create a new expression.

```
$modelTeam = Teams::find()
    ->select(['T.id', 'T.name', 'T.status'])
    ->addSelect([new Expression('IFNULL(T.image,"no-image.png") as DP')])
    ->from('{{%teams}} T')
    ->all()
```

Comment: With addSelect and having the new Expression into an array? What's the output?

Comment: here is complete code 

   ` $modelTeam  = Teams::find()->
                select(
                        ['T.id','T.name','T.status']
                        )
                ->addSelect([new \yii\db\Expression('IFNULL(T.image,\'no-image.png\') AS DP')])->
                from('{{%teams}} T')->all();
print_r(ArrayHelper::toArray($modelTeam));`
outputs 
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Pirates
            [status] => active
        )
)
`